# cin.getline() strange behavior

Tags: c++, queue, user-input, cin

the following is an exercise from a book for practicing some class inheritance. But the problem is in the client, not with the class design. (BaseCore, baseDMA, lacksDMA and hasDMA are the classes BTW).

```
// usedma.cpp -- polymorphic example (compile with dma.cpp)

#include <iostream>
#include "dma.h" // includes <iostream>

const int ELEMENTS = 1;
const int LENGTH = 30;

int main()
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;

    BaseCore *pArr[ELEMENTS];
    char tempDate[LENGTH];
    char kind;

    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEntering data for element #" << i + 1 << "\n\n";
        cout << "Enter the date it was created: ";
        cin.getline(tempDate, LENGTH - 1);
        cout << "Enter 1 for baseDMA, 2 for lacksDMA, or 3 for hasDMA: ";
        while (cin >> kind && kind != '1' && kind != '2' && kind != '3')
            cout <<"Wrong data. Please, try again: ";
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            continue;
        char tempLabel[LENGTH];
        int tempRating;
        cout << "Enter the label: ";
        cin.getline(tempLabel, LENGTH - 1);
        cout << "Enter the rating: ";
        cin >> tempRating;
        if (kind == '1') // baseDMA
            pArr[i] = new baseDMA(tempDate, tempLabel, tempRating);
        if (kind == '2') // lacksDMA
        {
            char tempColor[LENGTH];
            cout << "Enter the color: ";
            cin.getline(tempColor, LENGTH - 1);
            pArr[i] = new lacksDMA(tempDate, tempLabel, tempColor, tempRating);
        }
        if (kind == '3') // hasDMA
        {
            char tempStyle[LENGTH];
            cout << "Enter the style: ";
            cin.getline(tempStyle, LENGTH - 1);
            pArr[i] = new hasDMA(tempDate, tempLabel, tempStyle, tempRating);
        }
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            continue;
    }

    cout << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        pArr[i]->View();
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Done.\n";

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample execution:

> Entering data for element #1
>
> Enter the date it was created: 2012.01.01
>
> Enter 1 for baseDMA, 2 for lacksDMA, or 3 for hasDMA: 2
>
> Enter the label: lacksDMA
>
> Enter the rating: 15
>
> Enter the color: blue
>
> Date of creation: 2012.01.01
>
> Label: lacksDMA
>
> Rating: 15
>
> Color:
>
> Done.

It seems the Color member gets assigned the null character. This behavior happens inside both the `if (kind == '2')` and `if (kind == '3')` statements (with the style member in this case).

If I put a `cin.get();` just before cin.getline() it works fine but I have to press an extra key to make the program ask for input.

Why is this happening? If there was a '\n' pending in the input queue, cin.getline() would discard it and put '\0' in the variable, I can understand that. But the program asks me for the input for color and let's me enter it normally. Also, if I put a cin.get(), then the program shouldn't be waiting for an extra key stroke in the execution, it just should get rid of that extra '\n'.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @chris yeah, but as I put in the sample execution, the program let's me put the color. Shouldn't it just skip the Enter the color line?

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger, and see what get put in the strings?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg thanks for your answer. I'm so noob I don't even know how to do that. I'm just following my first book on the language. And this is an exercise from it.

Comment: @Kurospidey Until you get to the chapter on debugging, do some simple poor man's debugging by 'cout'ing the result tmpColor and tmpStyle directly.  Who knows, the issue might be something to do with the constructor's assignment of data and not getline

Comment: is it really necessary to post full code ?

Comment: @NeelBasu probably not, just added in the edit. Maybe someone wanted to test it on his own.

Comment: Even more important than the debugger is the ability to reduce code to a minimal complete example. You can strip out about half of the code in `usedma.cpp` and still get the error. That makes it much easier to find the bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << "Enter the rating: ";
        cin >> tempRating;
```

Unlike, `istream::getline()`, `operator>>` leaves the trailing `\n` in the stream. It causes the next call to `getline` inside one of your if statements to get empty input.

The stream is empty when control flow reaches `while (cin.get() != '\n')` statement at the end of for loop - it's waiting for input and it appears as if you're still inputing color.

Call `cin.ignore()` right after and it'll work.

Note that this kind of bug is immediately obvious if you put a "debugging cout" right after the input statement for color. There's one more issue with the way you're getting `tempRating`. If you enter invalid input, say "xy", the erros flags will be set on `cin` and the program will enter an infinite loop. Always check whether input operations suceeded.

Answer (score 1):

> If I put a cin.get(); just before cin.getline() it works fine but I have to press an extra key to make the program ask for input.

It seems to me that when you don't put the cin.get(), your getline is getting an empty character. Then, when you put the cin.get, you get that empty character and the your getline works fine..

But you should definitely go in debug to see exactly what's happening!

Comment: The cin.get() should be getting a newline character, or whatever you press if there's nothing in the input queue. What I don't understand is: if there's a '\n' in the queue, why does the program let me put the color and doesn't it automatically skip to the next line?

Comment: @jrok holly mother of god, that was driving me crazy and was so simple... Thanks a million, man. Maybe you should put this in your answer (I accepted it BTW), cause this is the thing that lighted the bulb for me. Thanks for your time!